# Can recurring events be displayed distinctively in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

When I schedule a frequently recurring event, it overwhelms the real events in the calendar.  That is, I quickly learn to ignore it, and so often fail to see the other events that are the same colour and appearance.

Is there any way to tell the calendar to mark these events (or the normal ones) differently so they don't look like each other?

(Note, a quick workaround would be to create a new calendar strictly for recurring events and give it a distinctive colour, but it would be nice to be able to explicitly add markers or flags or different colours to recurring events.)

Answer (score 2):

I adopted another simple trick:

as the first letter of the recurring event description, I use an emoji that stands out clearly.

In my case, a red dot (on a green calendar), but you can use something more meaningful, like a repeat symbol . Or you can do vice-versa, marking only the normal events.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the color is enough, you should be able to do that when you create or edit the event, just click the colored circle next to your or the organizer's name. There appears to be a bug where sometimes the color won't change across all recurring events, in which case if you're able to reschedule the meeting you can set the different color when you're recreating the event and that should work.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case this won't work, as it's part of a shared calendar and my color changes won't affect anyone else's display. ¶ I'm beginning to think that my "quick workaround" is the right solution, with everyone's recurring events being maintained in one common calendar.

Comment: Ah apologies, I didn't realize you needed it across other people's calendars as well. I think your separate common calendar is your best bet as well if that's the case.